# как в питоне вызвать функцию в функции?

Tags: python, функции

```
def reg(request):
    random_num = random_num()
    return render(request, 'user_code/auth2.html', {'random_num': random_num})

def random_num():
    num = randint(100_000, 999_999)
    return num
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

для начала нужно вызываемую функцию определить *раньше* вызывающей. а затем просто

```
def reg(request):
    return render(request, 'user_code/auth2.html', {'random_num': random_num()})
```

Comment: Ну и про то, что не надо переменные называть так же как функции, хорошо было бы добавить )

Comment: есть, Сэр!.....